# crystal report detail section doesn't repeat image for every record

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a VB 2012 Windows Forms Application that runs various Crystal Reports.  One of these reports is used to print coupons for customers who have referred other customers for membership within the organization.  The layout of the report uses an 8 bit PNG image in the Details A section of the report set to Underlay Following Sections in Section Expert.  The Details B section has fields that print the name of the customer and a unique barcode for each coupon created.  I'm creating the report on a 12x18 document and the report is set to Format with Multiple Columns so I can fit 6 coupons on 1 page in 2 columns (3 coupons per column).

When the report is created I'm having a problem where the image is not always repeated on every coupon.  The customer name and barcode both print in the correct place, but the artwork image is lost.  Running the report multiple times will cause the missing image to be in different records on each run.  Most times I can get 50 or so coupons that are fine before I encounter one that is missing the underlay image.

I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this.  Here is the code I use to generate the report if it helps.  The application imports a CSV file of data or orders with referrals into a DataTable called ordersTable.  I also have a CSV file of customer data that is imported into a DataTable called membersTable.  My reporting system doesn't interface with a database I can query, so I have to use these CSV files.  The two sets of data may be joined on a NameID value.  In the Orders file this NameID represents the customer who referred the customer that placed an order, while the Customer file has the names and addresses of the members who can refer new customers.

```
Private Sub ReferralCouponReport()
    LoadingForm.Show()
    Application.DoEvents()

    'create data tables to hold both import files
    Dim membersTable As DataTable
    Dim ordersTable As DataTable
    'import files into the datatable objects
    Dim imp As New Fmca.Common.ImportHelper.ImportHelper
    membersTable = imp.importCSVtoDataTable(membersText.Text, True)
    ordersTable = imp.importCSVtoDataTable(ordersText.Text, True)
    'create table of MembershipNo and MembershipName values from membersTable for each record in ordersTable using NameID as a cross reference value
    Dim query = (From o In ordersTable
                 Select o.Field(Of String)("NameID")).ToList
    'need a new table to add values to
    Dim couponsTable As New DataTable
    With couponsTable.Columns
        .Add("MembershipNo")
        .Add("MembershipName")
        .Add("CouponId")
    End With
    'Need a value for CouponId
    Dim sqlParams() As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    ReDim sqlParams(2)

    sqlParams(0) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(0).ParameterName = "@CouponType"
    sqlParams(0).DbType = DbType.String
    sqlParams(0).Value = My.Settings.CouponType

    sqlParams(1) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(1).ParameterName = "@CouponType"
    sqlParams(1).DbType = DbType.Int32
    sqlParams(1).Value = My.Settings.CouponSeries

    sqlParams(2) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(2).ParameterName = "@CouponSid"
    sqlParams(2).DbType = DbType.Int32
    sqlParams(2).Value = My.Settings.CouponSid

    Dim couponSid As Integer

    'Put the couponId assignment in Try block because the SQL could raise an error
    Try
        Dim couponId As DataSet = Fmca.Common.DBHelper.DBHelper.ExecuteDataset(Fmca.Common.DBEnum.DBEnum.DBServers.CONVERT, "sp_elan_GetCouponSid", sqlParams)
        couponSid = couponId.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2).ToString

        For Each value As String In query
            Application.DoEvents()
            'Get data from membersTable where NameId equals the NameID from the record in ordersTable
            Dim coupon = (From m In membersTable
                          Where m.Field(Of String)("NameID") = value
                          Select m).ToList
            If coupon.Count > 0 Then
                Dim memNum = coupon.Item(0).Item(1).ToString
                Dim memName = coupon.Item(0).Item(2).ToString

                Dim row As DataRow
                row = couponsTable.NewRow
                With row
                    .Item(0) = memNum
                    .Item(1) = memName
                    .Item(2) = couponSid
                End With

                couponsTable.Rows.Add(row)
            End If
            'Increment CouponSid
            couponSid += 1
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error creating coupons", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    'Update Coupon in database for the next available CouponSid
    ReDim sqlParams(2)

    sqlParams(0) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(0).ParameterName = "@CouponType"
    sqlParams(0).DbType = DbType.String
    sqlParams(0).Value = "MemberRecruitment_New"

    sqlParams(1) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(1).ParameterName = "@CouponType"
    sqlParams(1).DbType = DbType.Int32
    sqlParams(1).Value = 99

    sqlParams(2) = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    sqlParams(2).ParameterName = "@CouponSid"
    sqlParams(2).DbType = DbType.Int32
    sqlParams(2).Value = couponSid + 1

    Fmca.Common.DBHelper.DBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Fmca.Common.DBEnum.DBEnum.DBServers.CONVERT, "sp_elan_UpdateCouponSid", sqlParams)

    'Count number of coupons produced and send to Accounting to track as a liability on the GL
    Dim count As Integer = couponsTable.Rows.Count
    'Do nothing if the email sends successfully
    If SendEmailNotification(My.Settings.AccountingEmailAddress, count) = False Then
        Dim msg As String = ""
        msg += "The email notification could not be sent to " & My.Settings.AccountingEmailAddress & " at this time." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        msg += "Please notify the Accounting Department of the number of coupons and total liability amount that are shown below." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        msg += "Number of coupons:  " & count & vbCrLf
        msg += "Total liability:    $" & count * 10 & ".00"

        MessageBox.Show(msg, "Email Notification Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End If

    Dim rptDoc As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New RefCoupon

    rptDoc.SetDataSource(couponsTable)
    ReportForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

    LoadingForm.Dispose()
    couponsTable.Dispose()
    ReportForm.ShowDialog()

    rptDoc.Close()
    ReportForm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
    ReportForm.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    ReportForm.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm thinking the problem may have something to do with the 12x18 document size.

I changed it to a Letter (8.5x11) and the problem seems to have gone away.  I still don't understand why though, so if anyone can please elaborate I would appreciate any explanations provide.